# How to change recessed lighting with GU10 light bulb

Tags: lighting

[image]

How do I go about changing this lightbulb? 
The frame won't come out and there's no spring to pop out the bulb? 
Any and all help is greatly aplreciated!

Comment: Does the outer ring (black) pop off if tugged on a bit?

Answer (score 1):

You have to pull the outer potlight trim frame straight down and out of the ceiling.  Then you will be able to access the bulb from the back side.